# How to change color of different field in json data

Tags: android, json

I am using ...

> GUARDIAN_REQUEST_URL = http://content.guardianapis.com/search?from-date=2015-01-01&order-by=newest&show-fields=thumbnail&q=android&api-key=test

...  to parse JSON data. My app runs perfectly, but I want to change the color of different `sectionName` for e.g. for Technology = pink, for Society = blue.  Below is the screenshot of the app. Can anyone tell me how to change color of different sections?

[image: Screen Shot]

**NewsAdapter.java:**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {
Context mContext;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<News> news) {
    super(context, 0, news);
    mContext = context;
}

// "view holder" that holds references to each subview
private class ViewHolder {

    private final ImageView newsImage;
    private final TextView sectionName;
    private final TextView webTitle;

    public ViewHolder(ImageView newsImage, TextView sectionName, TextView webTitle) {
        this.newsImage = newsImage;
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
        this.webTitle = webTitle;
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    News currentNews = getItem(position);

    // Check if there is an existing view (called convertView) that we can reuse,
    // otherwise, if convertView is null, then inflate a new list item layout.
    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, null);

        final ImageView newsImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        final TextView sectionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_name);
        final TextView webTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.web_title);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(newsImage, sectionName, webTitle);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(currentNews.getThumbnail())
            .resize(100, 120)
            .into(viewHolder.newsImage);
    viewHolder.sectionName.setText(currentNews.getSectionName());
    viewHolder.webTitle.setText(currentNews.getWebTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

**QueryUtils.java:**

```
public class QueryUtils {

public QueryUtils() {

}

/**
 * Query the GUARDIAN dataset and return a list of {@link News} objects.
 */
public static List<News> fetchNewsData(String requestUrl) {

    // Create URL object
    URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

    // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
    String jsonResponse = null;

    try {
        jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link News}s
    List<News> newses = extractFeatureFromjson(jsonResponse);

    return newses;
}

/**
 * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
 */
private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}

/**
 * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
 */
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";

    // If the URL is null, then return early.
    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // If the request was successful (response code 200),
        // then read the input stream and parse the response.
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        }
    } catch (IOException e){

    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
            // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
            // could be thrown.
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}

/**
 * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
 * whole JSON response from the server.
 */
private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            output.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}

/**
 * Return a list of {@link News} objects that has been built up from
 * parsing the given JSON response.
 */
private static List<News> extractFeatureFromjson(String newsJson) {
    // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newsJson)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding news to
    List<News> newses = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJson);

        JSONObject response = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");

        JSONArray newsArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject currentNews = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String sectionName = currentNews.getString("sectionName");
            Log.e("SECTION_NAME", sectionName);

            String webTitle = currentNews.getString("webTitle");
            Log.e("WEB_TITLE", webTitle);

            String webUrl = currentNews.getString("webUrl");
            Log.e("WEB_URL", webUrl);

            JSONObject fields = currentNews.getJSONObject("fields");

            if (fields.has("thumbnail")) {

                String thumbnail = fields.getString("thumbnail");
                Log.e("THUMBNAIL", thumbnail);

                News news = new News(thumbnail, sectionName, webTitle, webUrl);

                newses.add(news);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newses;
}
}
```

**news_list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text="technolgy"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/web_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            tools:text="Amazon and Google fight crucial battle over voice recognition" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change color based on your sectioned by the below changge:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    News currentNews = getItem(position);
if(currentNews.getSectionName().equals("Technology"))
{
  viewHolder.sectionName.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourColor);
}

    // Check if there is an existing view (called convertView) that we can reuse,
    // otherwise, if convertView is null, then inflate a new list item layout.
    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, null);

        final ImageView newsImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        final TextView sectionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_name);
        final TextView webTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.web_title);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(newsImage, sectionName, webTitle);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(currentNews.getThumbnail())
            .resize(100, 120)
            .into(viewHolder.newsImage);
    viewHolder.sectionName.setText(currentNews.getSectionName());
    viewHolder.webTitle.setText(currentNews.getWebTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

**Switch case for color change :**

```
 switch (currentNews.getSectionName()) {
         case "Technology":
            viewHolder.sectionName.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourColor);// change color 
             break;

         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Color Set " + currentNews.getSectionName());
     }
```

Comment: To use switch statement which method do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is small change in json format

```
{
    "id": "technology/shortcuts/2017/jan/24/how-apps-plan-to-conquer-your-mobile-phones-lockscreen-",
    "type": "article",
    "sectionId": "technology",
    "sectionName": "Technology",
    "color": "#FFC0CB",
    "webPublicationDate": "2017-01-24T18:49:06Z",
    "webTitle": "How apps plan to conquer your phone's lock screen",
    "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/technology/shortcuts/2017/jan/24/how-apps-plan-to-conquer-your-mobile-phones-lockscreen-",
    "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/technology/shortcuts/2017/jan/24/how-apps-plan-to-conquer-your-mobile-phones-lockscreen-",
    "fields": {
        "thumbnail": "https://media.guim.co.uk/e30bdc920d576ce623441d999535159c0af8c201/0_255_4632_2778/500.jpg"
    },
    "isHosted": false
}
```

Check color field in json #FFC0CB this is pink hex code 
One of the Advantages of this is you can change color you want without touching or modifying APK file

And you can set this like

```
final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(currentNews.getThumbnail())
        .resize(100, 120)
        .into(viewHolder.newsImage);
viewHolder.sectionName.setText(currentNews.getSectionName());
viewHolder.webTitle.setText(currentNews.getWebTitle());
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(currentNews.getColor()));
```

Comment: Who work on back end !! means at server side tell them i want json format like this

Comment: In my project where to add this two lines to make changes?

Comment: this seems interesting. can you please explain me how to implement this ?